# How to send variables using HttpRequest using method post?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-headers, microsoft-metro

First, check this message which I was trying to do:

```
Login

To log on to Windows8 service is through the URL: http://app.proceso.com.mx/win8/login

This URL HTTP Request Method receives POST variables user and pass. The variable user is the user's email and pass the variable is the same password. In the event that the user or password are invalid return plain text number zero 0, in the opposite case, that the username and password are valid return plain text an alphanumeric string of 32 characters, as this b17f27a16589fee247c666da6ed15569, this string is the hash of the valid user valid and will run from 00:00 hours to 23:59 hours the day it was generated.

To test the URL was created: http://app.proceso.com.mx/win8/login_test 

Note: It should be clear that the hash generated will only be valid for Windows8 service to the user that gender and the effect from 00:00 hours to 23:59 on the day it was generated.

Note: All services generate text in UTF-8
```

Here is a test account:

- **User:** javier.lopez.contreras10@gmail.com
- **Pass:** policarpio20

So, if you set the data in this page: http://app.proceso.com.mx/win8/login_test you will receive a hash code.

And that's what I'm trying to accomplish in a metro application, but I feel lost in the situation. I have no idea to send those data to receive the hash code. I was using HttpClient and HttpContent but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to dharnitski for the code, right now I'm modifying this code for Win8 CP:

```
        // this is what we are sending
        string post_data = "user=javier.lopez.contreras10@gmail.com&pass=policarpio20";

        // this is where we will send it
        string uri = "http://app.proceso.com.mx/win8/login";

        // create a request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";

        // turn our request string into a byte stream
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_data);

        // this is important - make sure you specify type this way
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

        // now send it
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

        // grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
        //var a = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        String webResponse = requestReader.ReadToEnd();
```

And I realized, HttpWebRequest does not contain ProtocolVersion and is throwing me this error in this line:

```
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
// ERROR: The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation Failed.
```

How can I solve this problem if I can modify protocol version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an sample code to implement HTTP POST in C#

http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/05/05/send-a-https-post-request-with-c/

**IMPORTANT:** You must switch your web page to HTTPS (SSL). It is very bad practice to send not encrypted passwords.

Comment: thanks a lot, your link page did work out! Please, check my update